# Make autocomplete on text Input field using django-autocomplete-light 3.2.10

Tags: javascript, django, django-autocomplete-light

I have integrate django-autocomplete-light 3.2.10 successfully and it is working fine the issue is with its UI

In template it renders with `<select> <option>` html, after clicking on it a `span` get attached to it with input text field inside.

[image]

In form i am using *ModelSelect2* as widget.

```
widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='discovery:city-autocomplete')
```

> **`TextWidget`** is not supported in latest version 3.2.10

I just want the input text field directly visible to user. is there any possible way to achieve it with same library. May be i can create my own `CustomTextWidget`, or use some javascript to customize its UI

Comment: hi Satendra, you don't have to use django-autocomplete for this its too easy if follow this [post](http://setthecode.pythonanywhere.com/post?id=18) tell me if this helped you

Comment: @mohammedqudah yes by using jQuery it will be really easy, i am in favour. But i am curious to find a way if it is possible with this library. actually we are already using it in our project in other places.